# Как решить проблему с параграфами?OpenXML

Tags: c#, openxml

Возникла проблема с вставкой параграфа перед другим параграфом в OpenXML.
Попытка клонировать узел нужный результат не приносит.
При использовании метода **InsertBefore()/InsertAfter()** вылетает исключение *System.InvalidOperationException: "Операция является недопустимой из-за текущего состояния объекта"*

```
Body body = document.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph();
p1.AppendChild(new Run()).AppendChild(new Text("par1"));

Paragraph p2 = new Paragraph();
p2.AppendChild(new Run()).AppendChild(new Text("par2"));

body.InsertBefore(p1, p2);// тут кидает исключение
```

Библиотека DocumentFormat.OpenXml от Microsoft

Буду рад любой помощи)

Comment: какую библиотеку используете для работы с OpenXML?

Comment: @rdorn DocumentFormat.OpenXml от Microsoft